# Is the first day of a week Monday or Sunday in mainland China?

Tags: culture

Sounds silly, doesn't it? On the school calendar where I now stay, it is Sunday placed ahead of other days, but when my classmate made a mistake when failing to be in the class, he complained that the lesson on that Sunday in question he thought to be in another week.

Comment: Is there an actual Chinese language question here? Consider asking about a concrete Chinese-language vocabulary item or sentence.

Comment: @dROOOze A real language cannot exist outside the culture in which it is created and used, and I have already marked this a case of culture, so there is nothing wrong to have done so. So be constructive and tolerant.

Comment: Languages can't exist outside the people speaking them, their present and past usage, and their geographic territory either. That doesn't grant random questions on Chinese people, Chinese history, and Chinese geography without any Chinese language content.

Comment: @dROOOze I saw a shop sign 星期八鞋店, how should I understand it?

Comment: Is "understanding 星期八鞋店" the actual question you're looking for an answer to? Because that's a valid question but doesn't match your current question (which sounds completely different); you should update the question in this case.

Answer (score 2):

It starts on Monday in China, and also in many other parts of the world.

However there are also many other places that do start on Sunday.  Its not a perfect split, but generally the majority of the various american continents start on sunday, and other continents majority start on monday.

I think its understandable to mix up when not used to it, just like 12 vs 24 hour time, oz vs ml, lb vs kg vs stone, or any other difference of measurement system.  I guess it would depend on the specific situation if it was reasonable in that moment to not recognize the error happening//catch it before too late.

Answer (score 1):

In China,it's a common sense that the first of one week is Monday. here is a picture of our calender [image]

Comment: But mine shows the first day is Sunday, and it is also in mainland China.

Comment: @NanningYouth Some phones support the function to choose Monday or Sunday.